# POM version incompatibility integrating spring-batch-admin

Tags: spring, maven, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I've followed the answers in [Integrating Spring Batch Admin into an existing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438570/integrating-spring-batch-admin-into-an-existing-application?rq=1) to integrate `spring-batch-admin` into my application.

**Problem 1**

First I got the following error related to `slf4j`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:273)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
...
...
```

I got past this error (read: the error stopped but I don't know if it's the right way to solve it) by excluding the `slf4j` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Problem 2**

After the above workaround for problem 1, the following error presented itself:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
...
...
```

According to [Class Conflict when starting up Java project: ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in), this is caused by the use of multiple spring library versions.

**Questions**

1. Is the solution for problem 1 correct? Can I just exclude a dependency in a dependency's POM and expect things to work correctly (by using the slf4j version my project is using)?
2. Can problem 2 be solved in the same way? My application doesn't use all of the dependencies required by `spring-batch-admin`, so should I exclude the wrong version and include the right one?
3. This seems like a whole lot of hacking to get things to work. Is there a "better way"?

**Update**

Main pom file as requested. Some information has been removed for brevity. I've also removed private information:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>hidden.from.you</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>My Project</name>
  <modules>
    <!-- Modules listed here. About 20 in total. -->
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <!-- Profiles here. -->
  </profiles>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Caching -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Logging -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Spring -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Testing -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Lombok -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- HTTP Client -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <optimize>true</optimize>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.b1</version>
        <configuration>
          <header>license-header.txt</header>
          <aggregate>true</aggregate>
          <properties>
            <year>2014</year>
            <holder>Secret</holder>
            <email>private@notimportantnow.com</email>
          </properties>
          <strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
          <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.cgi</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.doc</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.dot</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.js</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.log</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.mcr</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.odt</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.pdb</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.pom</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.txt</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>failsafe-verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
              <configuration>
                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.1</version>
              <configuration>
                <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
                <ignoreAnnotations>false</ignoreAnnotations>
                <excludeRoots>
                  <excludeRoot>
                    target/generated-sources/groovy-stubs/main
                  </excludeRoot>
                </excludeRoots>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.10</version>
              <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3</version>
              <configuration>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/*.java</include>
                  <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                </includes>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.16</version>
              <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.6</version>
              <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
              <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <tagListOptions>
                  <tagClasses>
                    <tagClass>
                      <displayName>Tasks</displayName>
                      <tags>
                        <tag>
                          <matchString>TODO</matchString>
                          <matchType>exact</matchType>
                        </tag>
                        <tag>
                          <matchString>FIXME</matchString>
                          <matchType>exact</matchType>
                        </tag>
                      </tags>
                    </tagClass>
                  </tagClasses>
                </tagListOptions>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: I've added the main pom. Let me know if you also need the web submodule pom. This is the pom that add `spring-batch-admin` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the dependency hirarchie you see that the slf4j is comming from spring-batch-integration, ehcache-core and spring-batch-admin-resources. This means in other words your exclusions you've made could not work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions to make it work?